# aui input field with select dropdown

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have one text file with select dropdown as follows:

```html
<aui:field-wrapper cssClass="with-select">
    <aui:input type="text" name="productionCapacityParYear"
            label="production.capacity.par.year" inlineLabel="true">
        <aui:validator name="required"></aui:validator>
        <aui:validator name="number"></aui:validator>
    </aui:input>
    <aui:select name="productionCapacityParYearUnit" label=""
            inlineLabel="true">
        <aui:option label="production.units" value="" selected="true"></aui:option>
        <aui:option label="selection.ex" value="1"></aui:option>
    </aui:select>
</aui:field-wrapper>
```

But this select field comes in new line, but I want it in same line as the input. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use aui layout, so that those will be displayed in same line

Comment: Another option is to use `inlineField="true"` on the select field.